# Automating WSDL.exe in a Custom Build

Tags: asp.net, build-process, wsdl

I have a web application written in C# that consumes several internal web services.  We have a development tier, a testing tier, and a production tier.  Also, we use the `WSDL.exe` command to generate a `Proxies.cs` file for a given tier's web services.

When we are ready to deploy our code up the stack from development to test or test to production, we need to run the `WSDL.exe` command to point to the appropriate version of the web services.

Is there a generally accepted way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of way to do it.  A NAnt build script will do it, but I think the most commonly accepted method now is to use MSBuild.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Our company uses a combination of NANT + Cruise Control + Custom Utility apps to build our products.  More specifically, the  [task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) in NANT will allow you to fire off those command-line applications such as WSDL.exe